# Windows Phone 8 SDK installation failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sdk, windows-phone

I am trying to install WP8 sdk but it gives me following error.

[image]

I have `Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit` and using `Visual Studio Premium 2012`.

the setup file i used to install sdk is `wpsdkv80_enu1.img`.

Here is the log

```
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_EXECUTE_DEPENDENCY message to per-machine process.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to register the dependency on per-machine package.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to execute dependency action.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: Error 0x80070642: BA aborted copy of payload from: 'G:\packages\WPT\NuGetVPD2012.msi' to: C:\Users\DAWOOD~1.AHM\AppData\Local\Temp\{529db2e0-c334-4058-8ef0-9a214edbd1fa}\nugetvpd2012.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:35]: MUX:  Acquire Failed.  Retry acquiring after sleeping for 3 seconds, Retry Count: 2 of 3
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'G:\packages\WPT\NuGetVPD2012.msi' to working path: 'C:\Users\DAWOOD~1.AHM\AppData\Local\Temp\{529db2e0-c334-4058-8ef0-9a214edbd1fa}\nugetvpd2012'
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Failed to acquire payload: nugetvpd2012 to working path: C:\Users\DAWOOD~1.AHM\AppData\Local\Temp\{529db2e0-c334-4058-8ef0-9a214edbd1fa}\nugetvpd2012, error: 0x80070642.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CLEAN_PACKAGE message to per-machine process.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:0B20][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_CACHE_CLEANUP message to per-machine process.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send message to per-machine process.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to end session in per-machine process.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Error 0x800700e8: Failed to send message to per-machine process.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 2281472  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 2129920
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 162741399552 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 162741399552 bytes
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147024664 (0x800700E8), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Apply Failure
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[135C:16BC][2013-10-25T14:40:38]: Apply complete, result: 0x800700e8, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to update visual studio to the latest one (update 3) ?

take a look at this [solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/08/02/installation-of-visual-studio-2012-update-3-fails-with-error-the-pipe-is-being-closed.aspx) maybe it will work for you.